# Etherlords Won't Recognize it is Connected to the Internet

Tags: android, etherlords-2

My phone is connected to the Internet but the game Etherlords doesn't seem to recognize that it is connected to the Internet.

I tried:
1)  Connecting my phone with both my home WiFi and mobile network's Internet.
2)  Closing and reopening the app.
3)  Restarting my phone.

It seems to be able to connect to GooglePlay Services & load the new mission shards, but that's it.  I can't access the store, send/receive gifts to friends, or anything else that requires an Internet connection.  It just gives me pop ups saying I can't do that while offline.

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android version 5.0.1 (lollipop).

If anyone has a fix for this let me know.  Or if they know if I can uninstall/reinstall the app without losing all my progress since it stopped registering that it is online, then let me know that too!

Thank You in Advance!  :)